# How to select 2 columns with similar names from data.frames?

Tags: r

If this is the data

```
     data1=data.frame(date=c('01-01-2011', '04-05-2011',
               '02-09-2021', '11-11-2011'),
        va1=c(34,56,78,32),va2=c(34,56,78,32))

     data2=data.frame(mm=c('01-01-2011', '04-05-2011',
               '02-09-2021', '11-11-2011'),
        nnk=c(34,56,78,32),va2=c(34,56,78,32))
```

I want to compute cor between two columns with similar names in data1 and data2

```
     cor(data1$va2,data2$va2)
```

Comment: Try `nm1 <- intersect(names(data1), names(data2));
> cor(data1[nm1], data2[nm1])`

Comment: thanks, for this  cor(data1[nm1], data2[nm1])  i got error  it should be numeric

Comment: With your data, I didn't get an error as there is only va2 that is matching intersect and it is numeric.  Maybe you have some columns in your original data that are not numeric and is matching.  Try `nm1 <- names(data1)[sapply(data1, is.numeric)];nm2 <- names(data2)[sapply(data2, is.numeric)]; nm3 <- intersect(nm1, nm2); cor(data1[nm3], data2[nm3])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could `select` the columns that are numeric (`where(is.numeric)`), then loop `across` the columns that are `intersect`ing names with the 'data2', extract the corresponding column from data2 with column name (`cur_column()`) and do the `cor`relation

```
library(dplyr)
 data1 %>%
   select(where(is.numeric)) %>% 
   summarise(across(all_of(intersect(names(data2), names(.))), 
      ~ cor(.x, data2[[cur_column()]])))
```

Or with `any_of`

```
data1 %>% 
  select(where(is.numeric)) %>% 
  summarise(across(any_of(names(data2)), ~ cor(.x, data2[[cur_column()]])))
```